# Write Excel Sheet directly to response without creating any file on hard disk?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have developed a code to make excel file and write it to hard disk. I have to give a "Save as Excel" option on my webpage.

On click of this button i want to create excel dynamically and write it to the http responsestream without creating any file on disk.

I have done the same for a pdf by writing the file to disk and copying it to response stream as shown below

```
              // get your file as InputStream
              InputStream is =  new FileInputStream(dedupePDFPath);;
              // copy it to response's OutputStream
              IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
              response.setContentType("application/pdf");
              response.flushBuffer();
```

However this time i do not want to write file to disk. How can that be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) and write your Excel to any OutputStream:

```
HssfWorkbook.write(ServletOutputStream out);
```

FYI this works other dose not work

```
out.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                        //out.write(workbook.getBytes(), 0, workbook.getBytes().length); will not work
                        workbook.write(out);
                        out.closeEntry();
```